# Save Snapshot of pane to different sizes to file

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Is there a way to save the snapshot image to different sizes to the disk apart from the original size of the `pane_scene`. I've tried everything I found on the web including setting the parameters for the new Snapshot but I get an error. How do I alter the code below to save the snapshot image in 1080 * 1080 pixels? Thank you very much

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
private Pane pane_scene;
@FXML
private ImageView img;

    public void download()throws IOException {
        if (img.getImage() == null){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Note");
            alert.setHeaderText("Information");
            alert.setContentText("Please preview image first");
            alert.show();
        }
        else {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.setTitle("Save");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png", "*.png"));
            File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(new Stage());
            if (file != null){
                SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
                WritableImage image = pane_scene.snapshot(sp,null);
                ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image,null), "png",file);
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve but I am using the following technique to create render scale aware snapshots and I think that you can do something similar in your case. The trick is to provide an image of the right size and set an explicit transform.

```
public static WritableImage renderScaleAwareSnapshot(Node node, double renderScale, WritableImage writableImage,
        double x, double y, double width, double height) {
    int renderWidth = (int) Math.rint(renderScale * width);
    int renderHeight = (int) Math.rint(renderScale * height);
    if (writableImage == null || (int) Math.rint(writableImage.getWidth()) != renderWidth
            || (int) Math.rint(writableImage.getHeight()) != renderHeight) {
        writableImage = new WritableImage(renderWidth, renderHeight);
    }
    SnapshotParameters spa = new SnapshotParameters();
    spa.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(x * renderScale, y * renderScale, width, height));
    spa.setTransform(Transform.scale(renderScale, renderScale));
    return node.snapshot(spa, writableImage);
}
```

Comment: So will i make a recursive call for the method code you have provided in my download method?

Comment: What do you mean by "recursive" in this context? I don't see a need for any recursion. You just have to create the image with the desired size and then set the viewport and transform accordingly.

Comment: Thank you... But I'm a newbie and I'm struggling to know how to combine the code you've written with the one in have... sorry